# display img mysqli php - How can i solve it?

Tags: php, mysqli

i am training to add and display the img from the database, but i cant display the img from the database

i have used this code .. How can i solve it?

```
<?php
$conn = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if ($conn) {
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "name_of_db");
}

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Table_name");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
    $ID = $row->ID;
    $adi = $row->adi;
    $adres = $row->adres;
    $te11 = $row->Tel1;
    $tel2 = $row->Tel2;
    $TC = $row->TC;
    $Pasaport = $row->Pasaport;
    $Para = $row->Para;
    $Odedi = $row->Odedi;
    $foto = $row->fotograf;
    $Mekkeotel = $row->Mekkeotel;
    $Medineotel = $row->Medineotel;
    echo '<img src="' . $row->field_name_of_photo_in_db . '" border=0>';
}

?>
```

Comment: `$row->field_name_of_photo_in_db` => `fotograf` *maybe?*

Comment: i cant display the image from the database by my code .. where is the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You would recommend you not assigning all the information to separe variables, because it doesn't make any difference. You are just increasing your typing and you are basically losing more time. As for your question, change

```
echo '<img src="' . $row->field_name_of_photo_in_db . '" border=0>';
```

to

```
echo '<img src="' . $row->fotograf . '" border=0>';
```

and it should work fine now.

Comment: ...... yes its worked but its not seem as a photo , it seems as                                                                         Y§26^‹…‰dºvbÃ­Eç3Jñ»ŠN3Fà‡±Ïzn3GZr)<ÑaÜLz2EO RpjÉ¶F•‚åi®Ù5=Ä-bE@«»&Å&)Ê2p)84Úp øPÏävËûü~u½e©Ø_ö;ÛióÓÊ•[ùøG@//£I¥ äÉ¯ªþèÞÑ¬a¹€Ä/˜rìÙÇÒ5cÓ¨¤FWPÈÁ”ô äRÐ

Comment: What are you exaclty storing in this this database field?

Comment: i am storing longblob

Comment: @Raoslav Enev NightWarrior

Comment: Why aren't you storing the path to the image so you can easily access it from the databse?

Comment: it has been solved by echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row->fotograf ).'"/>';

Comment: also i have stored the path and its done ... also what do you prefer with online hosting or what is it better with online situation not local one longblob and uploading the image or getting the path of it?

Comment: I just upload the path to the image to the database and I don't have to do such things to show it up. For example, when you upload a picture, you update the image path to your field in the table.